# Laravel validation for numbers and hyphens

Tags: laravel, validation

How do you validate the numeric values with Hypen's (-) ?
I just want to validate the numeric value with Hypen's and without Hypen's.
Thank you so much !

For example 555 or 5-55

Comment: Please add the relevant code.

Comment: For example 555 or 5-55

Comment: Use: `preg_match("/^[0-9-]+$/", $input)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `preg_match` with the regex pattern `^[0-9-]+$`:

```
$input = "867-5309";
if (preg_match("/^[0-9-]+$/", $input)) {
    echo "MATCH";  // prints MATCH
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest for this purpose from the site:

https://www.phpliveregex.com/

use

For example, I wrote a preg_match in the link: ‌

https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/Ep6

You can see

My suggested code:

```
$input = "867-5309";
echo preg_match("/^[0-9-]+$/", $input) ? 'MATCH' : 'Not MATCH';
```